# XSLT- Refer to java custom method

Tags: xslt

I am quite new to XSLT and quite confused on how to use java inside XSLT.
I have an XSL template that will transform one XML to another. My requirement is to access an external java class method in my XSLT. 
I have a java class called FileCopy and its method is copyFile().
I need a way to access the copyFile() method inside my XSLT.

Comment: Is there some other way to do file copy during XSL transformation rather than making a call to an external java class? Does XSLT support file copy?

Answer (score 3):

You have to bind the extensions to the stylesheet. It should be via namespaces, class names, and the Java class path.

For example, define your class:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:filecopy="java:com.test.FileCopy"
  exclude-result-prefixes="filecopy">
```

and then you can use it:

```
<xsl:value-of select="filecopy:copyFile($params)"/>
```

More information is [here](http://cafeconleche.org/books/xmljava/chapters/ch17s03.html)

Comment: The class path comment is important of course. For testing what I do is, in the above example, put the java class in a sub folder test of a sub folder com of the folder that contains the style sheet so that it will be found by the xslt engine

Comment: I have my xsl file in say C:/transform. I placed my java file in C:/transform/com/test. Once i run the xsl i get the error -ERROR:  'Cannot find class 'java:com.test.FileCopy  '.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
Invalid factory configuration
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesh
eet

Comment: is "com.test" your package for FileCopy? I've just add it as example. If there is no package, you can try xmlns:filecopy="java:FileCopy".

Comment: I have a folder C:/transform and my xsl template and java class resides here. So now the structure will be C:/transform/test.xsl and C:/transform/FileCopy.java. 
when i run the xsl, i stil get the error i mentioned above "'Cannot find class 'java:com.test.FileCopy "

Comment: ok, can you open FileCopy.java and check package name at the top of file? If it does not exist, remove "com.test" in xstl file: xmlns:filecopy="java:FileCopy"

Comment: the package name does not exist, so i have modified the XSLT as below:<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:filecopy="java:FileCopy  " 
 exclude-result-prefixes="filecopy"> 
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />                I still get the error:(.

Comment: My error is : ERROR:  'Cannot find class 'java:FileCopy'.'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
Invalid factory configuration
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesh
eet

Comment: @nishMaria - I believe your problem is an extra space between `FileCopy` and `"` (end quote).  See the updated answer

Comment: May be related: specify the "java" namespace as indicated here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.text.xml.xalan.java.user/996.